# Expand variable inside Jenkins pipeline tool directive

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I would like to be able to programmatically decide which tool will be installed in an Agent for a Jenkins pipeline.

This is something I have that's working today:

```
withEnv(["JAVA_HOME=${tool 'OPENJDK11'}",
         "PATH+JAVA=${tool 'OPENJDK11'}"]) {
    ... do stuff ...
}
```

So I have a global tool `OPENJDK11` installed, along with `OPENJDK14`, and now I would like to change the Groovy script to be able to decide which JDK to install.

So before the part above I have saved the name of the tool in a variable `jdkToInstall`, how am I able to reference this variable inside the tool directive?

I have tried:

`${tool '${jdkToInstall}'}` and `${tool '$jdkToInstall'}`.

That doesn't expand my variable, so I get an error message saying it can't find the tool "$jdkToInstall".

I also tried with string concatenation, but that ended up with a similar error message with my plus and everything.

Comment: Following works for me `withEnv(["JAVA_HOME=${tool jdkToInstall}", "PATH+JAVA=${tool jdkToInstall}"]) {  ... do stuff ... }`

Comment: @Melkjot That works, thanks! :) Don't know why I didn't try that before. Provide a real answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is sufficient to expand (`${}`) the variable only once. Following works as expected:

```
withEnv(["JAVA_HOME=${tool jdkToInstall}", "PATH+JAVA=${tool jdkToInstall}"]) {  
  ... do stuff ... 
}
```